# track logged in user's cookie existence - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

By default, wordpress creates cookie for logged in users which looks like this:

```
Cookie Name: wordpress_logged_in_a32e4aa16e20e5346cda1
```

I checked wordpress core file(wp-includes/default-constants.php) from where this cookie is being created. And how I saw the cookiehash after `wordpress_logged_in_` is your site url done with md5().

```
if ( !defined( 'COOKIEHASH' ) ) {
    $siteurl = get_site_option( 'siteurl' );
    if ( $siteurl )
        define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( $siteurl ) );
    else
        define( 'COOKIEHASH', '' );
}
if ( !defined('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE') )
    define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE', 'wordpress_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH);
```

I need to check whether that cookie exists or has value like below:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['wordpress_logged_in_a32e4aa16e20e5346cda1']) && !empty($_COOKIE['wordpress_logged_in_a32e4aa16e20e5346cda1'])){
    //do something
}
```

But now I'm working on test website and the site url is different and once I go live, site url will be changed and cookiehash also will be changed. And I don't want to have issues after going live or after going live copy and paste new hash in my functions.php file.

Is there some dynamic way to check this cookie's existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the site URL variable using Wordpress function.

```
get_site_url();
```

Example

```
<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>
//Results in the full site URL being displayed:
http://www.example.com
```

After getting Site URL. Calculate its MD5 in PHP. Note that to use this function outside wordpress template files, You need include Worpress wp-load.php in your php code with its **path**.

```
<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>
```

Once MD5 is received you can concatenate string and use in your check. Let me know in comments if you have confusion.

**EDIT:**

```
$siteurl = get_site_option( 'siteurl' );
if ( $siteurl ){
    $hashedSiteUrl = md5( $siteurl );
    $finalUserCookieName = 'wordpress_logged_in_'.$hashedSiteUrl;
}

if(isset($_COOKIE[$finalUserCookieName]) && !empty($_COOKIE[$finalUserCookieName])){
    //some action
}
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly that some minutes ago. Thanks @Umar Hayat

Comment: Thats great @aidaghazaryan